# How do i make it so that questions are not repeated in this quiz?

Tags: python, list

Im making a quiz code and its multiple choice. but i cant figure out how to make it so the answers dont repeat in the multiple options (apple, banana, banana, pear). i tried removing them from the list but then the answers arent matching up with the questions. if theres a way to fix this issue please let me know.

```
questions_list = [
    "What is a network on a small geographical area called?",
    "What is the topology where every device is connected to each other?",
    "What is 8 bits called?",
    "Which of these is a type of malware?",
    "Which of these is a protection against malware?",
    "What is a set of rules also known as?",
    "What carries out logic instructions in a CPU?",
    "What stores the instructions that are to be executed?",
    "What is the name of the process of transferring data between the CPU and RAM?",
    "Which of these is a type of optical storage device?"
]

answers_list = [
    "A LAN",
    "The Mesh Topology",
    "A Byte",
    "Worms",
    "A Firewall",
    "A Protocol",
    "The ALU",
    "The RAM",
    "The Fetch-Execute Cycle",
    "A DVD"
    
]


score = 0

def ask_question(questions_list, answers_list):
    global score

  
    for i in range(len(questions_list)):
    
      # A separate answer list for each question so that the answers are not repeated
      current_answers_list = answers_list.copy()


      
      # Select a question from the list and the corresponding answer
      current_question = questions_list[i-1]
      current_answer = answers_list[i-1]


      # Remove the selected question and answer from the list so they are not repeated
      questions_list.remove(current_question)
      current_answers_list.remove(current_answer)

    
      # Add the correct answer to the list
      options_list = [current_answer]


      # Add 3 random answers to the list
      while len(options_list) < 4:
     
        random_answer = random.choice(current_answers_list)
        options_list.append(random_answer)
        
        # remove the random answer from the list
        current_answers_list.remove(random_answer)

      
      random.shuffle(options_list)
    
      
      # Print the question and the options
      print(f"""
      Question {i+1}:
      
        {current_question}
    
      Options:
        1.{options_list[0]}
        2.{options_list[1]}
        3.{options_list[2]}
        4.{options_list[3]}
        """)
      
      answer = int(input("Enter your answer (option number): "))
    
      # Valdation of option input (1-4)
      while answer not in range(1,5):
        print("Invalid answer")
        answer = int(input("Enter your answer (option number): "))
    
      # Check if the answer is correct
      chosen_answer = options_list[answer-1]
      if chosen_answer == current_answer:
        print("\nCorrect answer!")
        score += 1
        print("Your score is", score)
    
      else:
        # Show correct answer and deduct points
        print("\nIncorrect answer :(")
        print("The correct answer is", current_answer)
        if score > 0:
          score -= 1
        print("Your score is", score)

      print("\n")
```

i tried making a copy of the answer lists for each question and removing the ones i used so they are not repeated. the copy is reset after every question. but now the questions dont match up with the answers and sometimes the correct answer doesnt show up in the options.

Comment: Make a copy of the answers list and call `random.shuffle()` on it, then pick the first four answers from the list.

Comment: Instead of calling `random.choice` 4 times, use `random.sample(current_answer_list, 4)` to sample 4 different answers.